# Querying drupal nodes based on multiple term/node references

Tags: drupal

I need to query drupal nodes based on a taxonomy term which is several reference hops away from the content type I need to query.

I'm given a term id for a term which contains a term_reference. The referenced term contains a node reference. The referenced nodes are what I'm trying to get. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked into Relationships?

Comment: I need to do this in a PHP function, not through the GUI. The results are being fetched through an ajax function on the client side to populate a select box based on actions on the form.

Comment: To which Drupal version are you interested? Drupal 7 has the field API, and the code is quite different.

Comment: Probably D7...taxonomy terms don't have fields in D6.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are clean ways to do this, but I can't give very specific advice without actually seeing your data structure. I would start at the beginning and just `var_dump()` at every step.

For example, first fetch the term corresponding to the term ID you're given:

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
var_dump($term);
```

Look at the `var_dump()` to see how to access your term reference field. I'm guessing it will be something like this:

```
foreach (field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'YOUR_TERM_REFERENCE_FIELD') as $referenced_term) {
    var_dump($referenced_term);
}
```

Then see what you are given in there. Then, after that, do the same to fetch all of the referenced nodes.

The whole process will basically involve looping through each level, loading the references, looping through those, loading the references, and so on until you have the nodes you need. So you may end up with something like the following, assuming your term reference field is called `field_term_reference` and your node reference one is `field_node_reference`:

```
$nodes = array();
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
foreach (field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_term_reference') as $referenced_tid) {
    $referenced_term = taxonomy_term_load($referenced_tid['tid']);
    foreach (field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $referenced_term, 'field_node_reference') as $referenced_nid) {
        $nodes[] = node_load($referenced_nid['nid']);
    }
}

return $nodes;
```

Also, for what it's worth, after you finally are able to retrieve your nodes, you may want to go back through your code and combine some of the `foreach` loops into the D7 functions that load multiple entities, like `taxonomy_term_load_multiple()` and `node_load_multiple()`. This will reduce calls to the database and make things a bit more performant.

If you'd like a more specific answer, feel free to post more details about your data and I'll update my answer.